# Python - Iterate through list of website and scrape data - failing at requests.get

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I have a list of items that I scraped from Github. This is sitting in df_actionname ['ActionName'].
Each ['ActionName'] can then be converted into a ['Weblink'] to create a website link.
I am trying to loop through each weblink and scrape data from it.

My code:

```
#Code to create input data

import pandas as pd
actionnameListFinal = ['TruffleHog OSS','Metrics embed','Super-Linter',]
df_actionname = pd.DataFrame(actionnameListFinal, columns = ['ActionName'])

# Create dataframes
df_actionname = pd.DataFrame(actionnameListFinal, columns = ['ActionName'])

#Create new column for parsed action names
df_actionname['Parsed'] = df_actionname['ActionName'].str.replace( r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+','-', regex = True)
df_actionname['Weblink'] = 'https://github.com/marketplace/actions/' + df_actionname['Parsed']

for website in df_actionname['Weblink']:
URL = df_actionname['Weblink']
detailpage = requests.get(URL)
```

My code is failing at " detailpage= requests.get(URL) "
The error message I am getting is:

in get_adapter raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}") requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '0     [https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Truffle...\n1](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Truffle...%5Cn1)     [https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Metrics...\n2](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Metrics...%5Cn2)     [https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Super-L...\n3](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Super-L...%5Cn3)       [https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Swift-Doc\nName](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Swift-Doc%5CnName): Weblink, dtype: object'

Comment: It looks like you removed some parts of the error message. This is the critical detail for us to help answer your question. We will need to see the rest of the output with the URL to help you.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input data `actionnameListFinal` ? In other words, can you provide a [example] ?

Comment: I've copied the entirety of the error message and added code for a sample of the input data.

Comment: why are you inputting into `requests.get`  an entire pandas series (which is what `df_actionname['Weblink']` is and therefore what your `URL` is every time) ? wouldn't `detailpage = requests.get(website)` get you what you need instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a *single* valid url. Changing your `for` loop to

```
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
for website in df_actionname['Weblink']:
  detailpage = requests.get(website)
  pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(detailpage.content, 'html.parser')
  print(f'scraped "{pageSoup.title.text}" from {website}')
```

gives me the output

```
scraped "TruffleHog OSS · Actions · GitHub Marketplace · GitHub" from https://github.com/marketplace/actions/TruffleHog-OSS
scraped "Metrics embed · Actions · GitHub Marketplace · GitHub" from https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Metrics-embed
scraped "Super-Linter · Actions · GitHub Marketplace · GitHub" from https://github.com/marketplace/actions/Super-Linter
```

The way you were doing it, not only was your code basically trying to repeatedly sending the same GET request every loop (since `URL` was not dependent on `website` at all), the input of `requests.get` was not a single url, as you can see if you add a `print` before the request:
[image: screenshot]